# Compare 2 lists with .intersection()

Tags: python

I am trying to compare one list, list `A`, which contains 130 names with another list, `B`, that contains around 500 names. I want to check if names in list `A` are also present in list `B`, and if yes I want to crate a third list, `C` to store those common entries.

I tried to use the following method:

```
C = list(set(A).intersection(B['Username']))
for names in C:
    print('common user: ' + names)
```

The problem with this code is that I get some users but not all of them, I checked manually and it does not return all common users, where am I going wrong?
I tried to convert the lists `A`, `B` to `Series` and `Dataframe`, but when converting it to lists nothing changes, and while converting it to `DataFrame` it does not work.

Comment: Can you give us some data examples where it doesn't work ?

Comment: @Austin Your edit overwrote mine with fewer changes. I believe the system would have warned you about this. Please be careful not to supersede useful edits; that's why there is a warning message.

Comment: The lists are being opened with pandas and are excel files .xlsx

Comment: @tripleee I'll keep that in mind, but seriously there was no any warning messages.

Comment: @Austin Okay, thanks for following up.

Comment: B is not a list

Answer (score 1):

```
def intersect(list_1, list_2):
    return list(set(list_1) & set(list_2))
C = intersect(A,B)
```

Comment: the `list` wrapper is redundant. I'm pretty sure the OP meant just an iterable.

Comment: He literally mentioned 'C' is a list, so I wrapped it.

Comment: How is this solution different from what the OP has in the first line of the code? It's just the operator version of the very same operation, wrapped in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
C = [i for i in B['Username'] if i in A]
ser = pd.Series(C)
print(ser)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it works similar to my solution, I am still not getting all the common elements